# C# Webserver changing the Context in realtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Is it possible to write a Webserver in C# which i changing the Content in realtime like javascript doing it? So when i have a Clock for example it is showing or update it every secound? 
Like a TCP Listener with a Client?

Does someone has there Experience with or can someone give me a startpoint ?

Thank you

Comment: It is doable, but probably not a good idea (read network traffic). You can have service, and from your client you can poll it regularly, or you can use something like SingnalR which will push the data to your client at real-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is probably the best bet, it's pretty awesome. From their site:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

However, I would start by trying to do as much client-side (JavaScript) as possible. Simple AJAX will also take care of a lot of use-cases, especially when responding to user input, rather than constant polling. Only when real-time server communication is required should you go further.

There are some great introductory videos for SignalR on [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/) if you're interested in seeing what it's about.